# change fonts size when screen size changes using less

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Is there any way to change the font size when the browser is resized using less?
Without having to create different classes for each screen size.

Less style code

```
.banner-xlg-h1
{
    .hidden-lg;
    .hidden-md;
    .hidden-sm;
    .hidden-xs;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:36pt;
}
.banner-lg-h1
{
    .hidden-xlg;
    .hidden-md;
    .hidden-sm;
    .hidden-xs;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:30pt;
}
.banner-md-h1
{
    .hidden-xlg;
    .hidden-lg;
    .hidden-sm;
    .hidden-xs;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:24pt;
}
.banner-sm-h1
{
    .hidden-xlg;
    .hidden-lg;
    .hidden-md;
    .hidden-xs;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:18pt;
}
.banner-xs-h1
{
    .hidden-xlg;
    .hidden-lg;
    .hidden-md;
    .hidden-sm;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:12pt;
}
```

the above is what I have written so far. I have modified some of the bootstrap less code to have four screen sizes. Can I by using media queries combine the above to one class? if so how.

thank you

Comment: Have figured it out using less. It can be done using media queries.

Answer (score 2):

```
.banner-h1
{
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    @media (min-width: @screen-xs-min) and (max-width: @screen-xs-max)
    {
        font-size:12pt;
    }
    @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max)
    {
        font-size:18pt;
    }
    @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max)
    {
        font-size:24pt;
    }
    @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) and (max-width: @screen-lg-max)
    {
        font-size:30pt;
    }
    @media (min-width: @screen-xlg-min ){
       font-size:36pt;
    }
}
```

the above less style code code worked.